# Shadow service "user 'ftp': directory '/srv/ftp' does not exist"

Tags: arch-linux, users, shadow

Once in a while, my server throws this error when trying to run the shadow service. I can delete the users (http and ftp) but they keep reappearing. I don't want to add the directories, nor do I need the users. Why do they keep coming back and how can I stop this?

UPDATE: I just saw this during an update:

```
(17/35) upgrading systemd
Creating group ftp with gid 11.
Creating user ftp (n/a) with uid 14 and gid 11.
Creating group http with gid 33.
Creating user http (n/a) with uid 33 and gid 33.
(18/35) upgrading cockpit
```

- ArchLinux (I know, I know)
- dockerized everything except cockpit
- [Package list](https://pastebin.com/rJexQTgk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a discussion on the Arch Linux forums related to this issue: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=234525

As per this discussion, the users are created by the `systemd-sysusers` component. This component creates system users and groups and runs during the installation/upgrade of `systemd`.

The configuration files for `systemd-sysusers` are:

- /etc/sysusers.d/*.conf
- /run/sysusers.d/*.conf
- /usr/lib/sysusers.d/*.conf

You can `grep` through these files for the 'http' and 'ftp' users.

As per systemd conventions, oackages are expected to add files to the `/usr/lib/sysusers.d` path. You can override them at `/etc/sysusers.d`. To completely disable a package-provided config file, create a symlink to `/dev/null`.

Man pages: [systemd-sysusers(8)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/systemd-sysusers.service.8.html), [sysusers.d(5)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sysusers.d.5.html)

Comment: For arch, the file is located at `/usr/lib/sysusers.d/arch.conf`, I was able to comment out the lines pertaining to ftp and http. The users appear to no longer be created.